# Minimum transaction size for portfolio optimization with CVXPY

Tags: programming, portfolio-optimization, trade

Long time reader, first time asker!

I am working on a portfolio optimizer where I have a universe which is much larger than potential portfolio and where I want to exclude small transaction, i.e. a thresh-hold where the absolute value needs to be larger than "theta".

```
gamma = 1 # penalization of turnover

eps = 1e-5
prob = cp.Problem(
    cp.Minimize(Active_Risk #Active risk from target portfolio
                 + gamma * cp.norm(trade),
                ),
    [  # all weights sum to one or less
        cp.sum(w) <= 1,

        -1 + eps <= trade - buys,
        trade - buys <= 0,
        -1 + eps <= -trade - sells,
        -trade - sells <= 0,
        0 <= buys + sells,
        buys + sells <= 1,

        # set transaction limits
        trade  >= theta * buys, ## This is obviously wrong
        trade  <= -theta * sells,## This is obviously wrong

    ])
```

The issue here is how to create a mixed integer optimization problem out of this where the absolute value of the trade needs to be larger than theta or else 0.

EDIT: I think I have solved it by doing

```
# Indicator if the trade is larger than min_trade
        trade + 10 * (1-buys) >= min_trade*buys,
        -trade + 10 * (1-sells) >= min_trade*sells
```